# How to handle events without queue?

Tags: python, tkinter

If I change button color in click event. It happens after other events. For example here color is changed after sound finished.
How can I fix it?

```
import tkinter as tk
import winsound

def clicked():
    but['background'] = 'red'
    winsound.Beep(500, 2000)

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

but = tk.Button(frame, command=clicked)
but.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would probably be best to run the winsound in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think threading would be best here. I was able to get it to work with `root.after(10, lambda: winsound.Beep(500, 2000))` but that was a bit much and it still was blocking the visual of the button press during the beep.

Here is an option with threading.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import winsound

def clicked():
    but['background'] = 'red'
    threading.Thread(target=win_sound).start()

def win_sound():
    winsound.Beep(500, 2000)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

but = tk.Button(frame, command=clicked)
but.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```